# How to write unit test for upload file using HttpContext.Current.Request?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, file-upload, xunit, httpcontext

This is my Web Api Code for which i am trying to write unit test using xunit. In which i have to upload the file using HttpContenxt.Current.Request , I tried a lot to mock  HttpContext.Current.Request but this is not working. Please help me :( . How can I write unit test for HttpContext.Current.Request. How will I get object of HttpContext in unit test?

```
public ResponseData<UploadFileVM> UploadFile(FolderTypeEnum type)
{
  ResponseData<UploadFileVM> result = new ResponseData<UploadFileVM>();
  try
  {
    var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

    if (**httpRequest.Files.Count** > 0)
    {
      string fileName = **httpRequest.Params["name"]**;

      UploadFileVM data = new UploadFileVM();
      var fileData = **httpRequest.Files[0]**;
      Stream stream = fileData.InputStream;
      byte[] fileDataByte;
      using (var streamReader = new MemoryStream())
      {
        stream.Position = 0;
        stream.CopyTo(streamReader);
        fileDataByte = streamReader.ToArray();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Needs some clarifying information. Is the provided code snippet the actual controller action or a method in a service class used by the controller?

Comment: This is the Web Api upload method for which i have to write unit test cases

Comment: Ok with that clarification I can now tell you that it is very difficult to mock `HttpContext.Current` as it is very tightly coupled to IIS which is not present when unit testing.

Comment: You need to review your current implementation and take advantage of the built in members of ApiController.

Comment: Can you please suggest mi any other ways to do this? I am just stuck :(